# Can a corpse possessed by a Dybbuk be turned via Turn Undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead, possession

Will Turn Undead work on a corpse possessed by a [Dybbuk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dybbuk) (a demon listed in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*, p. 132)?

Background: I thought yes, as the creature is a raised corpse, an undead. However I was just listening to a podcast where the party faced a corpse possessed by a Dybbuk. The DM ruled (very convinced and prepared) that turn undead could not turn the creature. As far as I understood the argument, it's because it is actually the Dybbuk acting, which is not undead. While the DM can of course rule whatever he wants, it also makes sense to me. What would happen RAW? And if there is any RAI statements like tweets on it, that would also be nice to know.

Comment: Related: [What happens if you cast a resurrection spell on a corpse possessed by a dybbuk?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138266/35259)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### RAW, Turn Undead should work on a dybbuk possessing a corpse

The rules for the dybbuk's possession specifically state that:

> The dybbuk is now effectively the possessed creature. Its type becomes undead [...]

When it is possessing a corpse, it is an undead creature, and no further description or rules gives it any immunity to Turn Undead or other effects which specifically target or affect undead creatures. If it was immune to such things, there would not be much point to the rule that says its type becomes undead in the first place (except for its interactions with the mechanics of [raising the dead](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138266/35259), as noted by comments).

Outside of a corpse, the dybbuk is a fiend; inside a corpse, it is undead, with all the mechanical implications that entails. If the dybbuk doesn't want to be vulnerable to undead-busting effects, it should vacate the corpse.

Comment: I don't think "there would be basically no meaning to the rule that says its type becomes undead in the first place!" is a good argument. It for example prevents the dead creature to be resurrected using resurrection, as in this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138266/35259 This is explicitly about the dead body and not the dybbuk.

Comment: @findusl did I understand correctly, you ask about turning the dead body itself, not turning the dybbuk? what is the difference?

Comment: @enkryptor well the dead body is clearly dead and since it is moving its undead so you can't resurrect it. You are clearly resurrecting the body not the dybbuk. However when you turn it, you tell it how to act and the one controlling the acting is the dybbuk. So this one affects the dybbuk.

Comment: @findusl I'm not sure exactly what you mean here. The rules say that the dybbuk *is* now the possessed creature. So there is no difference between things that affect the dybbuk and things that affect the host body. And since the rules also say that the dybbuk is now undead as well it seems pretty clear. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "its type becomes undead" is relating to the dybbuk, not the host body.

Comment: True but it also says "The dybbuk is now effectively the possessed creature" so I would interpret turning the dybbuk as turning the body.

Comment: @enkryptor That is something I was not so sure about. I'm not saying your answer is wrong. I'm just saying that there could be meaning to turning the type undead apart from being affected by turn undead ;)

Comment: @findusl so, do you ask "what does it mean its type becomes undead", what consequences does this have? could you please reflect this in the question or (a better option) ask a new one?

Comment: No, I'm asking specially about the turn undead spell. If becoming undead has effects on that you can mention it, but generally asking about what becoming undead means is another question one could ask, but that's not mine.

Comment: Turn Undead targets the (Dead Body) which IS a (Dybbuk). In this scenario, Dead Body = Dybbuk. If the Dybbuk gains the type undead it can be Turned. The reason it gains Undead is so you cannot turn a Dybbuk when it is not possessing a dead body. There is no edge case here. Quit looking for agreement and look at the facts.